# How to setState of redux wrapped component?

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a component that is wrapped in Redux:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        component = await mount(
            <Provider store={buildStore()}>
                <CheckoutOverlay cartItems={basicCart} />
            </Provider>
        )

        await component.update();
    })
```

Things I've tried:

```
component.find(CheckoutOverlay).instance().state.coupon={} (Cannot read 'state' of null)
component.find(CheckoutOverlay).state.coupon={mode:0, value:.25}; (state does not update)
component.find(CheckoutOverlay).setState({coupon: {mode: 0, value: .25}}); (setState() can 
    only be called on class components)
component.find(CheckoutOverlay).instance().setState({coupon: {mode: 0, value: .25}}); (cannot read property 'setState' of null)

I've also tried some suggestions that use SHALLOW() and .dive(). But I always get the error 'dive()' is not a function. I am using Enzyme 3.11.0
```

How can I update the state of a component wrapped in the Redux Provider?

Additional Info:
Inside my component, CheckoutOverlay, I have another component that calls a function in CheckoutOverlay. This function stores the data sent in the State.
I am trying to simulate what happens when the data is sent to CheckoutOverlay.
The sub component has tests, and, I suppose, I can do something like simulate the click on that component. But that seems like it is more involved than  it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not mentioned what you are trying to test, I am giving you some general suggestions.

- You should not test the implementation details, rather test the functionality.
- If your state is dependant on the redux store state, you can pass the required data as initialState to your `provider`.
- You cannot use `instance` on a functional component

Comment: Thanks, I will add more details